# Convert array to a string in java

Tags: java, arrays, str-replace

Hy everybody,

I need to convert a array of long into an array (1,2,3,4,5)

```
new String[] {arrayTeste.toString().replace("[","(").replace("]",")")}
```

is this correct?

Comment: It's difficult to tell what's being asked here.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Convert the string of the form (1,2,3,4,5) to an array? Edit the question and make it proper.

Comment: OP wants to convert a `long` array to `string` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `StringBuilder` and append all array elements to it. It is more efficient than concatenating strings directly.

This is very much like `Arrays.toString()` does the job, but it does not require to replace the brackets afterwards:

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
b.append("(");

for(int i = 0; i < arrayTeste.length; ++i) {
   if(i != 0)
     b.append(",");

   b.append(arrayTeste[i]);
}
b.append(")");
String s = b.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you mean, you have to do:

```
long[] array = ...;
String string = Arrays.toString(array).replace('[', '(').replace(']', ')');
```

If you want to convert an array of `long` into an array of `Strin`g you can do this:

```
long[] array = ...;
String[] strings = new String[array.length];
for (int i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
    strings[i] = String.valueOf(array[i]);
}
```

In one line:

```
String[] strings = Arrays.toString(array).replaceAll("(\\s+|\\[|\\])","").split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your posts title I suppose you want to transform the content of the array into one formatted string.

Iterate over every item in the array and format accordingly:

```
string s = "";

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

    if (i == 0) s += "(" + array[i];
    if (i == array.length - 1) s += array[i] + ")";
    if (i != 0 && i != array.length - 1) {

        s += array[i] + ",";
    }
}
```

That should do the trick, roughly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Arrays.toString(long[])`